# Showing alert for multiselect with java script

Tags: javascript

I have the following Html code. It is a country list. I want to display that upon selecting countries single or multiple, it shows alert that which countries are selected. I am using following Code in JavaScript. I dun want to use Jquery or PHP or anything else..

```
 <select name= "countrylaw">
         <option value = "1">Afghanistan</option>
         <option value = "2">Albania</option>
         <option value = "3">Algeria</option>
         <option value = "4">Andorra</option>
         <option value = "5">Angola</option>
         <option value = "6">Antigua & Deps</option>
         <option value = "7">Argentina</option>
         <option value = "8">Armenia</option>
```

and here is my code in Java script but it is not working

```
        var select1 = document.getElementsByName("country");
        var selected1 = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < select1.length; i++)
        {
         if (select1.options[i].selected) 
            {
                 alert("File Selected for " + select1.options[i].value +" ")

            }
        }
```

Comment: There is no `name="country"` .First change it. `var select1 = document.getElementsByName("country");` to `var select1 = document.getElementsByName("countrylaw");`

Comment: "which countries are selected." - only one can be selected at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `onchange` event, like this:

```
var select = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];

select.onchange = function(){
    if(select.selectedIndex == -1) return null;   // if no option is selected

    // select.options is the list of selected options
    // select.selectedIndex is the index of currently selected option
    alert(select.options[select.selectedIndex].text); 
}
```

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/j6qYU/)**

You had simply run a one-time test with a for-loop. It wouldn't execute again if the user changes his selection, so, you have to use an event.

Answer (score 0):

To make your select box can be multiple-select, add `multiple` attribute to it.
To make your javascript run whenever user change the selection, add `onchange` attribute to it:

```
<select name="countrylaw" multiple onChange="showSelectedCountry(this)">
         <option value = "1">Afghanistan</option>
         <option value = "2">Albania</option>
         <option value = "3">Algeria</option>
         <option value = "4">Andorra</option>
         <option value = "5">Angola</option>
         <option value = "6">Antigua & Deps</option>
         <option value = "7">Argentina</option>
         <option value = "8">Armenia</option>
</select>
```

Then define the function callback:

```
showSelectedCountry = function(select){
    for(var i = 0; i < select.selectedOptions.length; i++){
        alert(select.selectedOptions[i].innerHTML);
    };
}
```

You can check the [demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ufL5w/).

Comment: actually, `function showSelectedCountry` would be clearer than `showSelectedCountry = function`, but it will not work on jsfiddle, so I change it.